# Combine regular expression together in OR?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm testing if `input class="k"` contains valid characters for the **HTML ID** attribute, showing an `alert` if not:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

I'd like to combine both regular expression in logical OR. **Is there a way to combine them in a single regex?**

```
$('.k').keyup(function(){
   if((/^[\d]/).test($(this).val())) alert('Not valid!');
   if((/[\s]/).test($(this).val()))  alert('Not valid!');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipe is the logical OR in a RegEx. In this case, parens are not necessary. However, usually, you want to group the subpatterns:

```
/(^\d|\s)/
```

The pattern for ID (`\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`):

```
/^[a-zA-Z][\w:.-]*$/
```

Comment: Note that `\w` is not necessarily restricted to `[A-Za-z_]` in every regex engine. Better be specific here.

Comment: @Tomalak you mean that `\w` is not always short for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` in javascript?

Comment: @Gremo not sure -- it _is_ in Java regexes, but for other languages, `\w` is locale dependent.

Comment: @Gremo In JavaScript, `\w` is equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. In other RegEx interpreters, `\w` can also include diacritics.

Answer (score 1):

As you know what an ID or NAME token must match precisely, you could write a regex to match only valid ones as such:

```
^[A-Za-z]([-\w:.])*$
```

If the input doesn't match that, you have an invalid match (note: `\w` matches digits and the underscore)